# Returing positions using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects and call my API using the value of the object. And then log in to the console. My API is returning the values needed, but the output is this:
`[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]`

My function:

```js
async function geoEncode() {
  const clients = [
    {
      nome: "John",
      address: "Jardim Planalto Sinibaldo Cassino 33",
    },

    {
      nome: "Joseph",
      address: "R. Afrizia Martins Sanacato - Jardim Natalia",
    },
  ];
  const baseUrl = "https://api.tomtom.com";
  const endPoint = "search/2/geocode";
  const format = ".json";
  const apiKey = "Hq2eTTQvtJRna5MMAsAsARlsQCxv5XjR";
  const clientsPositions = clients.map(async (client) => {
    const address = client.address;
    const position = await axios
      .get(`${baseUrl}/${endPoint}/${address}${format}/?key=${apiKey}&limit=1`)
      .then((response) => response.data.results[0].position)
      .catch((error) => error.detailedMessage);
    return position;
  });
  return clientsPositions;
}

geoEncode().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing multiple calls to the API and thus creating multiple promises. What you are seeing in the console is an array of those promise objects. You need to write code like below to wait for all of them to complete.

```
...
Promise.all(geoEncode()).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function geoEncode() {
  const clients = [
    {
      nome: "John",
      address: "Jardim Planalto Sinibaldo Cassino 33",
    },

    {
      nome: "Joseph",
      address: "R. Afrizia Martins Sanacato - Jardim Natalia",
    },
  ];
  const baseUrl = "https://api.tomtom.com";
  const endPoint = "search/2/geocode";
  const format = ".json";
  const apiKey = "Hq2eTTQvtJRna5MMAsAsARlsQCxv5XjR";
  const clientsPositions = Promise.all(
    clients.map(async (client) => {
      const address = client.address;
      const position = await axios
        .get(
          `${baseUrl}/${endPoint}/${address}${format}/?key=${apiKey}&limit=1`
        )
        .then((response) => response.data.results[0].position)
        .catch((error) => error.detailedMessage);
      return position;
    })
  );
  return clientsPositions;
}

geoEncode().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Promise.All () ensures that the array of all sync codes is executed successfully, and returns a single promise that resolves to an array of the results.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).